# how to define methods for a model that has a 1: 1 self relationship

Tags: laravel, orm, model, foreign-keys, relationship

I have this relational table on my db:
[image]

id, is referenced to: "attivitaSost" (and attivitaSpostata).
The relathionship is "optional" so the foreignkey is nullable.
But since the problem is the same, I will try to solve the first relationship first.

My model "cciActivities" have this 2 methods:

```
public function attOrig()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(CcieActivity::class,'id', 'attivitaSost');
    }

    public function attSpost(){
        return $this->belongsTo(CcieActivity::class,'attivitaSost','id');
```

If I set the inverse:

```
public function attOrig()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CcieActivity::class,'attivitaSost','id');
}
```

not works, and goes in a infinite loop thats goes in 500.

are  well written? who needs to carry the foreign key? the children or the parent? there is a standard or I make work as was thinking:

- save the new model,
- pick up the id,
- save it on the parent model,

The code:

```
                $ccieActPadre= CcieActivity::where('id',$ccieActivityId)->first();
                $ccieActivityNew = CcieActivity::create($data); 


                $ccieActPadre -> attivitaSost = $ccieActivityNew->id;
                $ccieActPadre->save();
```

I am asking this, because when i try to apply methods filters like

```
$ccieActivities = CcieActivity::doesntHave('attOrig')
                            ->get();
```

are returned not what i am expected.

When I am trying to render the resource activities, im using an api Resource like:

```
 return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'project' =>new ProjectResource($this->project)  , //id, nomeEnte, name, email, ruolo
            'catAttivita' => $this->catAttivita,
            'nomeAttivita' => $this->nomeAttivita,
            'descrizione' =>  $this->descrizione,
            'dataInizioPrevista' =>  $this->dataInizioPrevista,
            'dataFinePrevista'=> $this->dataFinePrevista,
            'numNegoziAderentiPrevisti'=> $this->numNegoziAderentiPrevisti,
            'numAziendeCoinvoltePreviste'=> $this->numAziendeCoinvoltePreviste,
            'numInfluencerPartecipantiPrevisti'=> $this->numInfluencerPartecipantiPrevisti,
            'numBuyerPrevistiB2B'=> $this->numBuyerPrevistiB2B,
            'budgetTotalePrevisto'=> $this->budgetTotalePrevisto,         
            'modalitaRealizzazionePrevista'=> $this->modalitaRealizzazionePrevista,
            'attivitaSpostata' => new CcieActivityResource($this->attOrigSpost),
            'attivitaSostituitaaaaa' => new CcieActivityResource($this->attOrig),

        ];
```

this part

```
 'attivitaSostituita' => new CcieActivityResource($this->attOrig),
```

never works! whatever method I apply!

So I need to understand which is the right convention to menage a 1:1 optional self relationship over a laravel model, thanks.

Comment: The foreign ID goes on who is created last. if you create the parent first, then the foreign id goes on the child.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eloquent nullable self relations 1:1 right logics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68211718/eloquent-nullable-self-relations-11-right-logics)

Comment: yeah, better edit that one with details than open a new one.

Comment: I close it instead...

Comment: Your question is opinion based. If you are encountering issues with your current setup, your question should focus about that issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @N69S thanks for point me in the right "askin" direction... is this one still "opinion based" ? there is no a standard way to make a self relationship 1:1? thanks

Comment: already answered in the first comment to **"there is no a standard way to make a self relationship 1:1?"** but it is still just an opinion.

Comment: how a orm system, your reply could be ok, but then i need to understand how to set "hasOne" and "belongsTo" and this ok is based on your reply but it will follow a standard? do not? ps i write these post after a long long search over stackoverflow and web too

Comment: i would say that using `hasOne` and `belongsTo` is recommanded by laravel https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one then again, it's open to discussion.

Comment: thats my starting point offcourse... but since my methods not works, in the case scenario that you suggest me hasOne(CcieActivity::class,'id', 'attivitaSost') and belongsTo(CcieActivity::class,'attivitaSost','id'); are ok?

Comment: That's my point, your question is not clear, **"are returned not what i am expected"** what are you expecting ? what are you getting as result ? can you add some example to your question. Why the foreign key is on the parent ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234437/discussion-between-n69s-and-jahstation).

Comment: edited with some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameters for `hasOne` and `belongsTo` are not the same.

`belongsTo` is for the related model and `hasOne` is for the local model

```
$this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

$this->belongsTo(User::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');
```

In your case, the `hasOne` has the wrong parameters. change it to

```
public function attOrig()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CcieActivity::class, 'attivitaSost', 'id');
}
```

EDIT:
Never [eager load by default](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default) the parent in the child model and the child in the parent model even if they are seperate Classes. It will lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: If i set as you told me, and i have "  return $this->belongsTo(CcieActivity::class,'attivitaSost','id');
" the app going in a infinite loop and 500 http

Comment: the only way thats seems make it works is set like this:  public function attSost(){
  return $this->belongsTo(CcieActivity::class,'attivitaSost','id');

 }
 public function attOrig()
 {

  return $this->hasOne(CcieActivity::class,'id','attivitaSost');

 }  BUT the methods returns both the same records, and not one the parent and one the son....

Comment: why is there an infinite loop ? which line does that ? did you modify the `toArray()` method of the model ?

Comment: $ccieActivities = CcieActivity::has('attSost')
                            ->get(); this is called inside a method that not use resource...so im more in control!

Comment: That line can not go into an infite loop, try using `paginate()` or `first()` instead of `get()`, maybe you have too many records and you dont have the proper indexes in place

Comment: there is 2 records on the table right now :D

Comment: what does this give you `$ccieActivities = CcieActivity::has('attSost')->toSql();`

Comment: "select * from `ccieActivities` where exists (select * from `ccieActivities` as `laravel_reserved_0` where `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = `ccieActivities`.`attivitaSost`)" thats looks pretty bad

Comment: That is the correct query, now how can that query do an infinite loop ? it can't, it must be somthing in your model, did you set the property `protected $with = array(...);` to load both parent and child ? so when the child is loaded it loads the parent and when the parent is loaded, it load the child and so on till eternity ?

Comment: That explains a lot, so when your relations are correctly set, you get an infinite loop error because it WORKS. and when it doesnt work, you dont get that infinite loop.

Comment: thanks thanks thanks for your patience, the problem comes extatly from the $with property on the model, if u add it to the reply i will set it as answer. thanks again both methods now works as espected

Comment: @JahStation so in the end, your question was missing details about your model, details about the infinite loop and details on proper debug. it was closed rightfully

Comment: @JahStation btw, this `'attivitaSpostata' => new CcieActivityResource($this->attOrigSpost),` can lead to the same infinite loop issue if you're loading the parent in the child ressource